# How to setup a c++ project for 2D graphics with hardware accelleration

Tags: c++, graphics, pixel, vertex, rasterizing

I'm trying to create a project in c++ that emulates the rendering pipeline to get a better understanding of how it works. I also want to use hardware acceleration (using compute shader programs) to increase the speed of the program, but I can't find much helpful information on the internet. I'm thinking of using OpenGL for the 2d graphics but to increase performance I need to disable the 3d rendering stage so I can have purely 2d graphics. The objectives of the program are

1. Vector object `vec<int size, T>`
2. Vertex object `vert a(vec<3,int> pos, vec<4,int> col)`
3. Place pixel `gfxPixel(vert a)`
4. Create Line `gfxLine(vert a, vert b)` (with interpolation)
5. Create face `gfxFace(vert a, vert b, vert c)` (with interpolation)
6. Matrices and other mathematical objects for 3d rendering (later on)

How can I use hardware acceleration for the graphics that I plan to implement with OpenGL for maximum speed? I plan to implement the functions from scratch (apart from the `gfxPixel` command as that seems to be fundemental). If theres any help on how I should setup this project that would be great help thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no 2D rendering acceleration in OpenGL.

You can use OpenGL for 2D graphics, though, if you simply ignore the Z coordinate. Set it to 0 in the shapes you render; set up an orthographic camera pointing along the Z axis so that only the X and Y coordinates make any difference. Actually, this is the default camera.

You will not make your program faster by using hardware acceleration to draw a pixel. It takes more time to send the command to draw a pixel than it takes to draw a pixel in a bitmap image on the CPU. If you are drawing many pixels, it makes sense to draw all the pixels in a bitmap image on the CPU, and then send the whole image to the GPU in one command. Or, you can send one command which draws all the pixels at once. The first option makes sense if you want to draw a whole screenful of pixels; the second option makes sense if you want to draw thousands of pixels (but not the whole screen).

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is how can I use compute shaders to speed up the functions I listed. Is there any way to bypass the 3D rendering to save time instead of setting the z coordinate to 0, because shouldn't the output to the screen only be 2D anyways.

Comment: How does the rendering pipeline make use of the GPU then if it's faster on the CPU?

Comment: @JoshuaPasa it doesn't render pixels

Comment: Then how does it render triangles? How does it take advantage of the gpu to do so?

Comment: @JoshuaPasa It sends the triangles to the GPU (many triangles per command), where they go through the rendering pipeline. Since you are trying to **emulate** the rendering pipeline, not use it for real, I assume you **won't** be doing that.

Comment: could I use compute shaders to do this?

Comment: @JoshuaPasa to do what, to write one pixel?

Comment: to process the triangles in the rendering pipeline

Comment: @JoshuaPasa Probably.

Comment: How would one implement these shaders?

Comment: @JoshuaPasa Well that's your project, isn't it? If your project is to implement the rendering pipeline in a compute shader, then asking how to write the shader is asking how to write a 3D rendering pipeline. Which is complicated.

Comment: fair enough, but you have been helpful thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of 2D / 3D graphics if you are using OpenGL. If you use Orthogonal projection you get 2D, if you use perspective projection you get 3D.

Your screen is 2D, perspective projection creates the illusion of 3D in your 2D screen.

Assuming you have hardware that has OpenGL acceleration (like OpenGL 4 or so), then you need to have proper drivers and library installed in your system. This has nothing to do with actual programming in OpenGL.

For drawing and texturing you may opt for GLSL (Vertex and Fragment Shaders) that way you execute your programs in the graphics hardware instead of spending most of the time in CPU.

A good starting point may be [this.](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Shaders)

And matrices are explained [here.](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/)

Comment: What's the fastest way to draw graphics and then show it to the screen?

Comment: @JoshuaPasa Use fewer vertex to draw your shapes. For example, for 2D you can draw rectangles (aka quads) and have them painted using a texture. As you can build a quad from two triangles (4 (x,y,z) values), it will be faster than drawing (for example) a sphere or a cube.

Comment: Should I use a shader program to determine the pixel color or should I use a program on the cpu

Comment: Using shaders gives you a programmable rendering pipeline. I have never benchmarked, but shaders should be faster than pure OpenGL v1 APIs (Fixed rendering pipeline). I would suggest going with shaders. Also, don't worry about performance if your project is not that complex. Unless you have billions of triangles or millions of polygons, I don't think you need to worry about performance.

Comment: It's just starting off 2d for now so I can eventually implement higher dimensions such as 3d,4d...Nd. I've managed to create a java program for this, but It's incredibly slow, so I was hoping that I could create my own graphics pipeline to handle this.

Comment: OpenGL will be way faster than Java. If you are planning to use JNI, keep in mind that it has overhead to copy data to and from the C++/C sides.

Comment: I've switched over to C++ for this reason, I'm just trying to create basic 2d graphics so I can upgrade to higher dimentions later. But I want to do it from as low level as possible. Such as a pixel, drawing lines and faces as fast as possible.

Comment: You should be fine then. alternatively, you can use game engines (Unity/Unreal) as they provide the abstraction and let you iterate on the logic faster. But they have their own learning curves. (Unity being the easiest, while Unreal being more performant)

Comment: @JoshuaPasa If your goal is to do fast rendering, then try asking "why is this rendering code so slow?" and show the code. (Note that improvements to working code normally fit on codereview.stackexchange.com, but since the slowness is a *problem*, you'd be asking how to fix a problem, which is allowed on Stack Overflow, and I'd recommend Stack Overflow because a lot more people will see the question.) (My example question might need some tweaking to make it a good Stack Overflow question, it's just an example)